# Command to show latest Drupal 8 version available

Tags: shell, drupal

I am looking for a way to display the latest Drupal 8 version available for download in a shell command.

I currently have this command which shows the current version available for the site installed:

```
drush core-status drupal-version | tr -d "Drupal version : "
```

This returns

'8.6.13'

I am now looking for a way to obtain the latest version number available to date which is

'8.6.15'

You used to be able to use

```
drush pm-releases drupal
```

to get this information. This post mentions using a feed to help get this information:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133925/find-latest-drupal-version-number

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
curl -w "%{url_effective}\n" -I -L -s -S https://www.drupal.org/8/download -o /dev/null | awk -F'/' '{print $7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
composer show -l drupal/core | grep ^latest
```

See documentation at: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show

Another option is:

```
composer outdated -a -D|grep ^drupal/core
```

You can probably get the complete list of available versions with:

```
drush php:eval '
    $ver = array_keys(
            ( update_get_available(TRUE) )["drupal"]["releases"]
        );
    asort($ver);
    echo implode("\n",$ver),"\n";
'
```